# How can I add conditions to my equation when using WorksheetFunction.MAX in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I add conditions to the `WorkSheetFunction.Max()` command in `VBA`.

I am working with two columns of data and would like to know the Max of column B, if column A equals 1.

I have tried a couple of different methods, and none seem to work.

Initially, I tried:

`MaxTaskNumbers = WorksheetFunction.Max(IF(Worksheets(AnalysisPart1").Range("A:A") = 1, Worksheets("AnalysisPart1").Range("B:B")))`

But I received the error

> Compile error Expected: expression

When I replaced `IF` with `IIF`, I received the error

> Argument not optional

Do you have any recommendations regarding how I can embed an `IF` statement in `WorksheetFunction.Max`?

Comment: Can you `if` an entire column?

Comment: "if column A equals 1" doesn't make sense.  Do you mean the sum total of column A is 1?

Comment: Yow are trying to use an array formula in vba.  Use the Worksheet.Evaluate() method.  Also as a side note, since it is an array formula you need to limit the range references, full column references will slow down the code when using array formula.  So find the extents and use that in the formula.

Comment: `=If(Max("A:A")=1,Max("B:B"),"")`? (*What* in column A needs to be one? Just switch out the first part with that...)

Comment: @BruceWayne it is an array formula `=MAX(IF(A:A = 1,B:B))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - What does `If(A:A=1)` check? If the whole column sum is `1`? If the only thing in there is `1`? Etc.??

Comment: @BruceWayne It iterates through column A if any cell =1 it adds the value in Column B to an array to find the max.

Comment: So better off to loop through rows, for every A cell =1, add cell B value to array, then find max of array? Edit: er don't even need array, just test each new number to existing and replace if greater.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Woah, there's a lot going on in such a small formula!

Comment: @BruceWayne that is why we need to limit the reference range to that only with values.